# Is there a way to make the route mapping based on specific path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I code lots of ASP.NET but I'm kind of new with .net MVC, I've a default route registered like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

And I want to add another Administrator area on the site and all the URL would be something like "http://localhost/Administrator/controller1", "http://localhost/Administrator/controller2", etc. I've lot of controllers in the Administrator namespace and I'm trying to register those controller with only one MapRoute, I did something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Administrator_default", "Administrator/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Administrator", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

it works with those controller but one problem is that in some other controller while I try to do a redirect like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Forum");
```

Then I'll always be redirect to http://localhost/Administrator/Forum instead of http://localhost/Forum, it's not a big issue but make the URL looks strange, I tried to restrict to certain namespace but it's not working. It looks just as I'm trying to register two default route and .Net just match the first one, I'm wondering is there a way to make it two default route and map on only specific path only?

Comment: Are you executing the RedirectToAction within a controller that is in the Administrator Area?

Comment: I'm executing RedirectToAction within other controllers, the main point here is I didn't realized there is a Areas function, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact issue is why `Areas` were added to MVC 2. http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_2

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Zach's answer.

1. Not ideal, but you do have the option to have controllers in the controller root folder (e.g. /controllers/HomeController.cs) of your project as well as the controllers in Areas (maybe high level root pages that display menus for areas).
2. Secondly a quick tip on using the RedirectToAction method. You can specify the area you would like to redirect too using the route parameters e.g:

   RedirectToAction("Index","Form", new { area = "MyOtherArea" });